# preg_match capturing period \. in non-capturing group

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I can't seem to keep periods from being captured in a simple PHP preg_match !

```
$pattern = '/(st(?:\.)?)/i';
preg_match($pattern, '1617 5th ST.',$match);

var_dump($match);
```

Prints:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "ST." [1]=> string(3) "ST." }
```

What is going on here??

Comment: Why are you capturing `st` ? A simple `/st\.?/` is the same thing.

Comment: good question:
/(st(?:\.|reet)?|b(?:lvd\.?|oulevard))/i      etc. for address matching

Comment: `/st(?:(?=\.)|reet)?|b(?:lvd(?=\.)|oulevard)/i` Bam, no dots, no capture group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a non-capturing group placed inside the capturing group so it will be part of your captured match result. To avoid this, you can place the optional dot outside of your capturing group.

```
(st)\.?
```

Answer (score 0):

Use look ahead instead

```
$pattern = '/(st(?=\.))/i';
preg_match($pattern, '1617 5th ST.',$match);

var_dump($match);
```

matches only `ST`

Answer (score 0):

```
(st)(?:\.)?
```

What you need is this.Your regex `(st(?:\.)?)` here `.` is getting captured in the main

```
                           ^  ^ 
                      group1  group2(non capturing but inside group1)
```

groups along with `ST`.you have asked your second group to be non captured.